# What are the exact levels when each tier of spell books becomes available?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When googling this question, I only found forum arguments about this as well as approximate guesses.

So I'm now looking for more accurate answer: At which level of each magic skill do spell books of each tier become available at their respective merchants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote UESP:

> Most spell tomes can be purchased from merchants. Novice- and
>   apprentice-level spell tomes can be purchased from the regular spell
>   vendors found in each of Skyrim's cities. Also, adept- and
>   expert-level spell tomes only appear in the mage's merchandise when
>   your magic skill is high enough (40 for Adept and 65 for Expert
>   spells). After reaching the required skill level, you must wait for
>   the mage's merchandise to be reset (typically two days in-game), or,
>   save, then attack the merchant and reload, before the new tomes will
>   appear. Master-level spell tomes can only be acquired once that
>   school's ritual spell quest has been completed.

Comment: Another way that is never mentioned on reloading the merchandise, is to quit the game entirely and restart/reload it.

Comment: TLDR: It's not your level, it's your skill in the appropriate school of magic. 40 for Adept spells, and 65 for Expert.